# Will Truecrypt replace my grub bootloader?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, grub, truecrypt

I use the grub bootloader to dual boot win7 and ubuntu. now i want to use truecrypt to encrypt my windows disk. if i do this, will my grub be gone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/system-encryption) its optional.

" By default, Windows 7 and later boot from a special small partition. The partition contains files that are required to boot the system. Windows allows only applications that have administrator privileges to write to the partition (when the system is running). TrueCrypt encrypts the partition only if you choose to encrypt the whole system drive (as opposed to choosing to encrypt only the partition where Windows is installed)."

IE if you encrypt the whole system drive it will overwrite your boot loader, but if you leave the boot partition, Truecrypt can be launched from that for the rest of the drive.